# Get stream from absolute Uri

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I'm working with Windows Phone 7 and I have a very difficult problem. Please help me !
I want to get a stream form an absolute uri (from web) of a png image. But GetResourceStream method work only with relative uri. Then I found imagetool form http://imagetools.codeplex.com/ but to now my problem is not still solved.
Could anyone give me a solution ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you need the image? Do you want to display it immediately? store it? give us more context so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple Code Image stream from Absolute url and store to isolated storage

```
namespace eQuadrigaWP7
{
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _imgURL;
public string imgURL
{
get
{
return _imgURL;
}
set
{
if (value != _imgURL)
{
_imgURL = value;
}
}
}
private BitmapImage _Image;
public BitmapImage Iimage
{
get
{
return _Image;
}
set
{
if (value != _Image)
{
_Image = value;
}
}
}

public void LoadIimage()
{
if (this.imgURL == null) throw new Exception("Error equadriga log");
HttpWebRequest downloadthumbnailrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(this._imgURL));   ///this is main
DownloadThumbNailState thumbnailState = new DownloadThumbNailState();
thumbnailState.AsyncRequest = downloadthumbnailrequest;
downloadthumbnailrequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleThumNailDownLoadResponse),
thumbnailState); 
 }

private void HandleThumNailDownLoadResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
DownloadThumbNailState thumbnailState = (DownloadThumbNailState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
HttpWebRequest downloadthumbnailrequest = (HttpWebRequest)thumbnailState.AsyncRequest;
thumbnailState.AsyncResponse = (HttpWebResponse)downloadthumbnailrequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
Stream imageStream = thumbnailState.AsyncResponse.GetResponseStream();
byte[] b = new byte[imageStream.Length];
imageStream.Read(b,0,Convert.ToInt32(imageStream.Length));
imageStream.Close();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.SetSource(ms);
String tempJPEG = "logo.jpg";

using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
{
myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
}
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
fileStream.Close();
this.Iimage = bmp;
}
});

}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
if (null != PropertyChanged)
{
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
public class DownloadThumbNailState
{
public HttpWebRequest AsyncRequest { get; set; }
public HttpWebResponse AsyncResponse { get; set; }
}
}
}


ItemViewModel imageitem = new ItemViewModel();
imageitem.imgURL = "http://www.yoursite.in/bilder/9780199738663/titel.jpg";
imageitem.LoadIimage();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`?

```
var uri = new Uri("http://chriskoenig.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/givecamp_125125_ad.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.BeginGetResponse((ar) =>
{
    var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(stream);
            MyImage.Source = image;
        }
    });
}, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
        BitmaiImage bmp=new BitmaiImage();
        Image image=new Image();

        Uri url = new Uri("http://Ur url", UriKind.Absolute);
        HttpWebRequest reqest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        reqest.BeginGetResponse(DownloadImageCallback, reqest);    

    void DownloadImageCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(result);
        Stream s = responce.GetResponseStream();
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            bmp.SetSource(s);
            image.Source=bmp;
        });
    }
```